# Using Azure Function in timer mode to populate a Storage Table

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, azure-table-storage, azure-iot-hub

I'm trying to send data to the Azure Storage Table using a Function with timer schedule in node.js.

```
module.exports = function (context, myTimer, outputTable) {
    var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();
    context.log('JavaScript timer trigger function ran!', timeStamp);   

   context.bindings.outputTable = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        context.bindings.outputTable.push({
            PartitionKey: "Test",
            RowKey: i.toString(),
            Name: "Name " + i
        });
    }
};
```

function.js:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myTimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "0 5 * * * *"
    },
    {
      "type": "table",
      "name": "outputTable",
      "tableName": "contmaticfunc",
      "connection": "contmatic9acd_STORAGE",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}
```

The code run without any error, but i can't see the data on the table. 
I am not sure about the argument function outputTable. Am i missing anything?

Best regards

Comment: Could you tell me which Azure function app version you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my test, we can use the following steps to send data to the Azure Storage Table.

1. Add Azure Table storage as output binging

[image]
 2. Code

```
module.exports = async function (context, myTimer,outputTable) {
    var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();

    if (myTimer.IsPastDue)
    {
        context.log('JavaScript is running late!');
    }
    context.log('JavaScript timer trigger function ran!', timeStamp);   

    context.bindings.outputTable = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        context.bindings.outputTable.push({
            PartitionKey: "MyTest"+ i,
            RowKey: i.toString(),
            Name: "Name " + i
        });
    }

    context.done();
};
```

[image]

3. Check

I use PowerShell to check it

```
Install-Module AzTable

$groupName=""
$accountName=""
$tableName=""
Connect-AzAccount

$table = Get-AzTableTable -resourceGroup $groupName -storageAccountName $accountName -TableName $tableName
Get-AzTableRow -Table $table
```

[image]